# Manually submit crash reports

Tags: macos, crash

When an application crashes, OS X usually presents a little dialog with the opportunity to [report the bug to Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/8892/2392).

However, in my current situation there seems to be a problem with the window server so although I get the aforementioned dialog, I cannot interact with it, and hence cannot submit the crash report. A reboot is required to make the system once again responsive.

But I’d really like to get this report to Apple because it’s symptomatic of a problem with Lion which regularly crashes my machine, and I’d like to get this fixed as soon as possible.

There seem to be [two alternatives](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/11789/2392) here:

1. Use the [feedback form](http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html) on Apple’s website
2. Use [bugreport.apple.com](https://bugreport.apple.com/)

Neither is ideal: the first is aimed at non-technical customers and doesn’t really offer the  possibility to provide technical details, let alone crash reports. The second presents a website that seems to date from the 90’s and apparently hasn’t been touched since. That, and I’ve already submitted a bug report there once, which has subsequently been deleted without comment. Neither fact instils much confidence in me that Apple actually cares about this platform.

Ideally, **I’d like to trigger the “report a crash” dialog manually.** Is this somehow possible? I haven’t found any way to do so in Console.app.

Comment: Apple’s bug reporting application sucks so much that there’s finally a campaign demanding that it be fixed: http://fixradarorgtfo.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the opt in status is no Longer present in the Lion Console app, you can't see whether you are opted in or out.

My system does resume sending non-received reports when the next crash or force quit happens. I would poke and force quit the problem and watch that all the reports get submitted.

It is extra hassle to file it formally at http://bugreport.apple.com - but that way you are assured a human or two touches the report rather than it going into the summary reports.

Comment: And no - I can't figure a way to trigger it manually ;-) sorry...

Answer (score 1):

The [xattr](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html) command can display user comments that were within a crash dialogue.

### Displaying a comment: example

```
sh-3.2$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.8.2
BuildVersion:   12C60
sh-3.2$ xattr -p comments ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SIMBL\ Agent_2012-10-20-193649_macbookpro08-centrim.crash
These crashes of SIMBL Agent are negligible. 
sh-3.2$
```

### Adding a comment without the crash dialogue

As `xattr` can display comments, so you might use `xattr` to add to a .crash file that is without comments.

#### Example

```
sh-3.2$ xattr -p comments ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SIMBL\ Agent_2012-10-20-092340_macbookpro08-centrim.crash
xattr: /Volumes/gjp22/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SIMBL Agent_2012-10-20-092340_macbookpro08-centrim.crash: No such xattr: comments
sh-3.2$ xattr -w comments "test in relation to <http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69026/8546>" ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SIMBL\ Agent_2012-10-20-092340_macbookpro08-centrim.crash
sh-3.2$ xattr -p comments ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/SIMBL\ Agent_2012-10-20-092340_macbookpro08-centrim.crash
test in relation to <http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69026/8546>
sh-3.2$
```

## Submission of reports

From the [man page for `SubmitDiagInfo`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/SubmitDiagInfo.8.html):

> **SubmitDiagInfo** is a system process which runs periodically. If the user has opted-in for automatic reporting of diagnostic and usage
>   information, then **SubmitDiagInfo** collects and sends to Apple any
>   recent diagnostic information which has not yet been sent to Apple.
>   **SubmitDiagInfo** also cleans up any diagnostic and usage information which was created more than one month ago and is no longer needed.

### Previous submission date

```
defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.SubmitDiagInfo PreviousSubmissionDate
```

#### Example

```
sh-3.2$ defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.SubmitDiagInfo PreviousSubmissionDate
2012-10-15 19:29:15 +0000
sh-3.2$
```